# Liquid transition effect in CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want something [like this](https://dribbble.com/shots/15238746-The-Journey-of-LeBron-James-Homepage)

I have tried using `feTurbulence` and `feDisplacementMap`, but the result is not satisfactory.

Unable to switch between two images.

```
<feDisplacementMap
  id="feMap"
  scale="1"
  in2="wrap"
  result="feMap"
  xChannelSelector="R"
  yChannelSelector="R"
  in="SourceGraphic"
>
  <animate attributeName="scale" values="300;1;" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
</feDisplacementMap>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.